# SQL Server subquery

Tags: sql, sql-server, subquery

Can I write a subquery inside another sub query?

Here what I have written for connect three tables (`DBO.SalesPerson`, `DBO.Orders`, `DBO.Customer`) but it does not work in SQL Server.

Query

```
SELECT 
    name    
FROM 
    DBO.SalesPerson    
WHERE 
    id = (SELECT 
             salesPersonId    
          FROM 
             DBO.Orders    
          WHERE 
             DBO.Orders.customerId = (SELECT id     
                                      FROM DBO.Customer     
                                      WHERE DBO.Customer.name = 'Samsonic'));
```

Is there any method for do this task??

Comment: use in instead of "="

Comment: You should look up "joins"

Comment: First of all - ***what*** *does not work* - do you get an error? If so, please post the **complete and precise** error message(s) you get. Also: why on earth do you want to do it this way? Just use two simple `JOIN`s and you're done .... much simpler, and quite possibly faster, too ....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You *can* use nested subqueries, but for something like this you should just join the tables:

```
select
  p.name
from
  DBO.SalesPerson p
  inner join DBO.Orders o on o.salesPersonId = p.id
  inner join DBO.Customer c on c.id = o.customerId
where
  c.name='Samsonic'
```

Answer (score -1):

or you can write the SQL query without sub queries

```
SELECT DBO.SalesPerson.name

FROM DBO.SalesPerson,DBO.Orders,DBO.Customer 
WHERE 
DBO.SalesPerson.id=DBO.Orders.SalesPersonId
and DBO.Orders.customerId=DBO.Customer.id
and DBO.Customer.name='Samsonic'
```

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**more than 20 years** ago) and its use is discouraged. ***Please*** stop suggestions something that's been retired for **over 20 years** now! Use the **proper ANSI JOIN**s instead....